# How to find one-to-one relation in between two columns with duplicates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like the following:

import pandas as pd

```
dict1 = {
    "idx": [1, 2, 9, 1, 1, 6, 1, 3, 2],
    "value": ["a1", "b1", "c1", "t1", "t1", "f1", "r1", "l1", "b1"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
```

Here, `a1`, `t1`, `r1` always occur with `1`. To verify this, I used the following code,

```
def one_to_one(df, col1, col2):
    first = df.groupby(col1)[col2].count().max()
    second = df.groupby(col2)[col1].count().max()
    return first + second == 2

one_to_one(df, 'idx', 'value')
```

But it returned `None` even though `a1`, `t1`, `r1` always occur with `1` and others do the same. How to verify that, `a1` for example, only occurs with `idx` = `1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `drop_duplicates` based `idx` + `value` combination. If each `value` has only one `idx`, then the result should contain the same number of records as the number of unique values in `value` column:

```
len(df[['idx', 'value']].drop_duplicates()) == df['value'].nunique()
# True
```